# Checking for null and a value in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I want to check a value in an SSRS report to make sure that it isn't null, first, and then that it equals a particular value. My expression is as follows:

```
=iif(IsNothing(First(Fields!RecordStatusFlagId.Value, "DataSource")),"",(First(Fields!RecordStatusFlagId.Value, "DataSource") = 1,"","DELETED"))
```

So if `RecordStatusFlagID.Value` is not null and it doesn't equal 1 write "DELETED". Otherwise write "".

However, this gives me the error:

> Error 75  [rsCompilerErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘textbox21.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30198] ')' expected. C:\Reports\MyReport.rdl 0   0

which doesn't make sense since I've verified that all of my parentheses are closed and matched.

Is it even possible to use an expression as the second term in the `IsNothing` operator?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add an `iif` to the second portion of the `IsNothing` expression

```
=iif(IsNothing(First(Fields!RecordStatusFlagId.Value, "DataSource")),"",iif(First(Fields!RecordStatusFlagId.Value, "DataSource") = 1,"","DELETED"))
```

Comment: Can anyone expand on this answer? I'd prefer to accept something more complete that others could benefit from.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simplify that into a single iif() statement:

```
=iif(
    First(Fields!RecordStatusFlagId.Value, "DataSource") <> 1 
    And First(Fields!RecordStatusFlagId.Value, "DataSource") Is Not Nothing
    , "DELETED"
    , ""
   )
```